# Running sports simulations using Apache Spark

Tags: java, class, apache-spark, distributed-computing, simulator

I would like to change my current Java project to distribute work through Apache Spark. 
I am building a simulator for sports outcomes - currently the project looks a bit like this:

Controller class
Simulator class
GameState class

The controller class takes care of all the user input and edits the GameState.
The simulator's run method is called whenever the GameState changes and works out the new outcomes.
I have already profiled and optimized, as well as parallelising the simulator class onto all threads on my CPU but it is still too slow when doing many simulations - hence the desire to scale up CPU cores.

I'm trying to learn the basics of Map Reduce and Spark and I understand the basic word count example. Is there a slightly more complex set of examples I can work from? I suppose I need to find a way of broadcasting the GameState to each node, running the simulation and then reporting back.

But can I wrap an instance of the GameState class as an RDD? Can I wrap the simulator's run method as some sort of mapping function? I'm not sure what spark is capable of in these cases..

Answer (score 2):

The power of Spark and Map Reduce is in being able to apply functions to lots of rows of data with the same structure to transform or reduce them.  For example, reading temperature readings and finding the highest temps for each city.  The scalability of these technologies comes from the fact that you aren't sharing state between your parallel processes at all.  You can provide the same supporting data at the start if for example you have a lookup table that all workers need, but you can't update state in one worker and have it be visible to another.

Simulations aren't natural fits for Spark/MR since they typically would require some sort of global state you are updating.  That being said it depends on what computations you need to do during your simulation update step.  If there lots of independent computations then you might be able to make it work.

One other comment, there is a cost to running stages in Spark.  It takes a little time setup the stage before it is actually running.  This means Spark is often not well suited for cases where you want to lots of quick back to back computations.  It is better when you can give it a large chunk of data that will take some time to chew on.

You could look at other technologies.  For example Akka is a pretty solid parallel processing library that lets you easily create and communicate with threads/processes across multiple machines.  Spark uses that internally to manage it's distributed processes.

Without knowing more about your simulation problem and design it's hard to give more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks! Yes each simulation is totally independent and will just return an array of numbers, the reducing step I can probably do quite quickly myself. But perhaps you are right with the stop and start, each simulation only takes 1ms, I just want to do loads..Akka looks great thanks!

Comment: You might be able to use spark then.  The key executing code with spark methods is any data/objects you pass in via closurers must be serializable.  However once you are in the function running on the executor you can instantiate whatever you want.  If you need to reuse the object across input rows look at mapPartition instead of map which gives you an iterator over the rows in the partitions so you can do some setup before processing.